# Anyone know the name of this Star Wars Novel?

Tags: story-identification, star-wars

Read it back around 2002. I think the story takes place in an alternate timeline or something like that because in this novel the Jedi were able to stop Palpatine and his coup d'etat. This also marks the end of the Clone Wars.

Actual story takes place 10 years after the Clone Wars. It starts with a refugee/immigration council on some planet in the mid-rim region being taken over by a Terrorist group known as 'Crying Sons'. And concurrently, the Jedi Order/Council gets infiltrated by a couple of suicide bombers thereby killing a lot of Jedi like Mace, Obi-wan, Anakin, Plo-koon etc.

Meanwhile, the terrorist group that took over the immigration council, demand Chancellor Ava to issue a statement announcing the discontinuation of the Outer-Rim Refugee Policy within 48 hours or else the hostages will be killed.

The Outer-Rim Refugee Policy was first introduced sometime before the start of the Clone Wars. The policy basically allowed refugees from the outer-rim worlds into the mid-rim worlds. It was used by the industrial mid-rim worlds as an opportunity to hire cheap labor force.

Yoda having barely survived the bombing, gets immediately contacted by Chancellor Ava. And she asks his help to resolve this situation quickly. I think she, initially before contacting Yoda, sent in a special assault team, but the situation proved to be more than what they could handle. And one of the member also gets caught.

Yoda seeing the Jedi in disarray decides to call in the Phantoms. The Phantoms are like a "Special Forces or Blackops" like Jedi like team. However, the group operates without the official consent of the Republic or the Jedi Order/Council. And this is due to a bill passed long time back by the Galactic Republic that restricts forming such entities within the Jedi. So a very few people know about the Phantoms. Phantoms have been for as long as Jedi have existed. Only making their presence when needed the most. Yoda describes them as a, "*Necessary evil, that does what normal Jedi must not.*"

The Phantoms team consist of only 4 members. The leader Wong a male human, Ixtl a female alien but human like features, a male Togorian and an IG-85 droid. Except for the droid all the other 3 members are incredible skilled force and lightsaber users. They employ both light and dark side force techniques and skills.

After the Phantoms quickly quell the terrorist threat at the immigration council, the story mainly focuses on Wong and his team investigating further into the terrorist group and the suicide bombers. And trying to figure out if there is any connection between them. Or was it just some mid-rim world citizens frustrations over losing some jobs to the immigrants/refugees.

As they investigate further, I think some conspiracies start to surface up. I think they also discover some crystals in the suicide bombers body that repelled the force. Thereby allowing them to infiltrate easily inside the Jedi order. Yoda worries as their invisible enemy is able to even stalk and toy with the members of the Phantoms, whose teamwork Yoda considers to be impeccable. Furthermore, the situation between the outer-rim refugees, mid-rim citizens and the Republic deteriorates as time goes on. I think it reaches a point where mid-rim worlds declare the mid-rims region as an autonomous zone or something like that.

The pressure is on for Wong and his team as they desperately race against time to try get closer to their invisible enemy who is two to three steps ahead of them, resolve the situation and all the while trying to prevent the leak of their existence to the public.

I think eventually with help from Chancellor Ava they are lead to a senator name Vyak Gall and his Cabal. I don't remember what happens much after this though. I think Wong and his team are trying to find some evidence that links Vyak Gall but a civil war or something like that breaks out between mid-rim worlds and the Republic.

Let me know what the name of this novel is. I like to complete it.

Comment: Where did you read this story?  Knowing how you found it might help us track it down.  And how accurate are the names you list?  Are they accurate down to the spelling, or phonetic translations from memory?

Comment: None of my Star Wars novels contain any characters called Vyak Gal, Vyak, Gall, Ava or Wong.

Comment: I'm pretty sure [Chancellor Ava](https://mazerunner.fandom.com/wiki/Ava_Paige) is from Maze Runner

Comment: Could it be a fan-fic instead? From your description, it sounds a lot like one. Helping us determine the exact medium (official SWs novel, comic, fan-fic) can helps us spot it :-)